# Convert void *(void * const   mAudioData)  to Short *   using  Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, primitive-types, short, speex

i have `AudioQueueBuffer`'s Audio Data which has  `void * const`  format. i want short array (`short *`) Audio data for my codec.

How to Convert void * const to Short * in Objective c???  type cast from void to short possible ? or i have to use some byte order conversion like `OSReadBigInt16`??? if so sample for conversion? please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Objective-C is just like C for typecasting.  That means if you want to interpret your `void *` pointer as a `short *` pointer, all you need to do is:

```
(short *)voidPointer
```

If the bytes aren't in the right order (ie, endianness mismatch), you'll need to deal with that too - there's no way to tell if that's the case based on the information in your question, though.

Comment: thanks for fast reply . i need above conversion for IOS device. and one more thing i have typecast unsigned char from void *(which is 8 bit) ,it works fine. if i type cast to short(16 bit) is possible???

Comment: You can't dereference a `void *` at all, so who cares what 'size' the data it points to is?  It's totally up to you and the specifics of your program if it's going to work or not.  What is the data pointed to by the `void *` pointer?  Is it 16-bit binary data?  If so, a simple typecast is fine.  If not, you have more work to do.

Comment: Check the documentation for the API that gave you the pointer.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question ? how to find void *'s pointer? whether 16 or 8 bit? presently i have AudioQueueBuffer struct ,how i can i get short from this ? i have referred AudioQueueBuffer but they doesn't specify abt void pointer ?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Check out that link.  It looks like you probably want to be using `AudioQueueGetProperty`.

Comment: I'd love to +10 because you brought up the endianness issues.

Answer (score 1):

`void*` is a convention for declaring untyped pointers. Such pointers need to be *re-interpreted* as pointers to some data type. Whether or not it works depends on what you or the API put at the address pointed to by the `void*` pointer: if it is a sequence of `short` values with no gaps, a simple cast to `short*` is going to work; otherwise, you may need to perform additional conversion.